# Cannot get response from express endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I'm building an API that I intend to use with my react native application. The problem which I'm facing right now is that I when I try to hit this particular route `/api/auth/signup` in `Postman` I get the **Could not get any response** error message.

This is the route:

```js
//create user token
router.post(
  "/signup",
  [check("username").isEmail(), check("password").isLength({ min: 6 })],
  async (req, res) => {
    //validate input field on the backend
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    const { username, password, firstName, lastName } = req.body;

    try {
      //search DB if there is an existing user
      let user = await User.findOne({ username });

      if (user) {
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: "User already exists" });
      }

      const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);

      res.status(200).json({ data: salt });
    } catch (error) {}
  }
);

module.exports = router;
```

The strange thing is that if I remove the `User.findOne` function I get a response. I don't know why this keeps happening, as I had built a similar application following the same pattern without a problem.

NOTE: In the main app.js I have the `app.use(express.json({extended:true})`, I've also successfully linked the routes in the main file too. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you should put something in your `catch` statement in case you're getting an error?

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for the suggestion, tried it but still had the same results sadly..

Comment: Can you share your app.js and User model file?

Comment: Are you sure you don't see any error in the console if you update the catch block like this: `catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).send("Check console for error detail");
    }` And also are you sure mongoose connection is successfull?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out when I was requiring mongoose in one of my models I required it with an uppercase letter `const mongoose = require('Mongoose')` which isn't valid, therefore the findOne method won't run because there's no model to take it from. Strange that visual studio code didn't complain about the false import. Anyways, thanks to anyone willing to help me out :) !

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo in your `app.use...` statement which you've given in your comment as,

```
app.use(express.json({extented:true})
```

which needs to be corrected as, (`'d'` should come in place of `'t'`)

```
app.use(express.json({extended:true})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey David, 

thanks for the suggestion and nice find with the typo. Sadly the typo isn't in the code itself, rather just here, becase I was in a hurry and forgot to tripple check everything, will edit it now!